# Index by more than one parameter?

Tags: node.js, lucene, neo4j

I'm creating an index for my user nodes called 'users', where the key is 'email' (with the users email as value).

So far so good - I can easily get users by email.

My user nodes also hold the user name (user_name) as a property and I am trying to query the db in way so I can tell if 'email' or 'user_name' are taken.

Of course, they can be used in different nodes.

I'm looking for a cypher query or a way to "index by more than one parameter" so I can tell if email or user_name were already used.

Thanks!

I'm talking about neo4j by the way, calling it from node.js using node-neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the auto-index to index both `email` and `user_name` and then run a query like this:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index("email:john@doe.com user_name:"John Doe"')
return n
```

Answer (score -1):

If we talk about Lucene, you could add to index documents, that contains two fields - user name and email. Your code could be something like this (very raw example in Java, I think Node.js, should have similar syntax, when workis with Lucene)

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("userName", userName), Field.Store.YES,  Field.Index.ANALYZED);
doc.add(new Field("email", email, Field.Store.YES,  Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

And after that, search easily for this two fields.

As reference - take a look at Lucene In Action (http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/) or similar books over Internet.

Comment: Hi, Actually I'm using neo4j for that so the answer I'm looking is more specific to it.